# Complex numbers in fomula in R

Tags: r, complex-numbers

I have this formula:  `A(k) + iB(k) + C(k)e^(5 * pi() * i * k/12500)`
where  (for example)  `B(k) =  sin(k * pi()/20)` and `k = 1, 2, 3,..., 2500`

How should I write this formula in R?

How

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` are numbers, you can write `a + bi` exactly like that in R, e.g. `1 + 2i` is legal in math or R.  To write `i`, use `1i` and `iB(k)` is `1i * B(k)`.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine.